# Use end keyword as a variable in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, keyword

One of my project's resource have an attribute 1.story (integer), 2.start(date_time) and 3.end(date_time). Now the issue is I can not create a Factory for this resource for test cases. The reason is 'end' key word. I want something like...

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :my_factory do
    story "My story"
    start '2013-12-09 14:48:29 +0530'
    end Time.now                                                 
  end                                                                  
end
```

That's why I want to use end key word as a variable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you are doing yourself a favor by doing it that way. You should honestly consider using something other than "end"!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't and **really** shouldn't use a ruby keyword as a method name.

There are other words you can use, such as *halt* or *stop*.

Comment: My project is so much bigger the problem is that I cant change these variable names please suggest me something else.

Comment: It is **not** possible because it would create an ambiguity: how does ruby interpret the "end" word: a call to the end method or the end of the block?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way around changing your "end" to something that is not a Ruby keyword. If you were to change the definition of this keyword all your other code would fail since its bound to this keyword whenever you used it. So even if your project is big: changing the name is the faster and not to say ONLY option you have!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but wanted to throw my hat in the ring

you can do

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :my_factory do  
     {
        "story" => "My story",
        "start" => "2013-12-09 14:48:29 +0530",
        "end" => Time.now
      }                                       
  end                                                                  
end
```

This will help you avoid using the end keyword and you probably just need to override it anytime you plan to use the factory or you can try turning the above hash into a trait

```
   FactoryGirl.define do 
      trait :my_factory do  
        example_attribute do
           {
            "story" => "My story",
            "start" => "2013-12-09 14:48:29 +0530",
            "end" => Time.now
          } 
        end                           
      end                                                                  
    end
```